# Replacing whitespace with sed in a CSV (to use w/ postgres copy command)

Tags: linux, postgresql, sed

I iterate through a collection of CSV files in bash, running:

```
iconv --from-code=ISO-8859-1 --to-code=UTF-8 ${FILE} | \
    sed -e 's/\"//g' | \
    sed -e 's/, /,/g' \
    > ${FILE}.utf8
```

Running `iconv` to fix UTF-8 characters, then the first `sed` call removes the double quote characters, and the final `sed` call is supposed to remove leading and trailing whitespace around the commas.

HOWEVER, I still have a line like this in the saved file:

```
FALSE,,,, 2.40,,
```

The `COPY` command in postgres is kind of dumb, so it thinks " 2.40" is not valid syntax for a numeric value.

Where am I going wrong w/ my processing of the CSV file? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Probably what is happening is that you have more than one space or more than one field that has a space, and so you are seeing the results of a single successful trailing-blank substitution on a line that had more than one.

BTW, you can give multiple -e arguments to sed. Try this:

```
... | sed -e 's/"//g' -e 's/ *, */,/g'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second `sed` only removes trailing spaces (in fact, only a single trailing space).  What here is supposed to remove leading spaces?

Comment: Forgetting leading spaces.. its not removing a single trailing space, either.

Comment: You don't know that; if it had *two* trailing spaces, you get one on output.  That was what I meant by the parenthetical.

Answer (score 0):

Do a construct one of this to remove spaces:

```
sed -e ':a; s/, /,/g; ta'
sed -e 's/,[ ][ ]*/,/g'
```

The first one will recursively perform updates till it finds no matching combinations.
Second one will search for space followed by a possible group of spaces.

And it is not necessary to remove `"`, as by default PostgreSQL understands them when using [`COPY ... WITH (FORMAT CSV)`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-copy.html)

Answer (score 0):

A general **alternative** to preparing the CSV to fit the data-types exactly is to import all data as `text` (into a temporary table with `text` columns) and let the PostgreSQL type-coercion mechanisms do some of the work automatically.

In particular, leading and trailing white space is trimmed automatically when a `text` is cast to a numeric type or date / time type. Try:

```
SELECT '   234 '::text::int;
SELECT '    23.4 '::text::float8; -- incl. a leading tab
SELECT '    2012-12-1    '::text::date; -- incl. a leading & trailing tab
```

So if you have a table like:

```
CREATE TABLE foo
( id    integer,
  col_a date,
  col_b double precision
);
```

You can:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE foo_tmp  -- dropped automatically at end of session
( id    text,
  col_a text,
  col_b text
);
```

```
COPY foo_tmp FROM '/path/to/foo_file.csv';
INSERT INTO foo
SELECT id::int
      ,col_a::date
      ,col_b::double precision
FROM   foo_tmp;
```

Or use [any other Postgres function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html) to prepare the string as needed.

All you need is a valid CSV format.