# Formatting Date(YY:MM:DD:Time) in Excel

Tags: excel, postgresql, date, csv

I have an excel  file, with a date column, but I want to convert the date column to

**YY/MM/DD/Time**

Ive been searching for 2 hours and no result yet.

This is my data:

**Source Data:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/75zbS.jpg

**Expected Output:** YY/MM/DD/Time

Can someone help me how I can do it? I want to insert it into postgresql and I want to change everything to compatible date format.

EDIT: I have tried Right Click -> Format cells -> date but it does not change anything!

Thanks

Comment: First use text to columns to set the column as a date, then format it however you want.

Answer (score 2):

You could use this method and split the date and time into separate cells:

```
=DATE((LEFT(A1,4)),(MID(A1,5,2)),MID(A1,7,2))

=TIME(MID(A1,10,2),(MID(A1,12,2)),0)
```

Once your date value is in a format Excel can recognize, you can then change the formatting to whatever you'd like.

Or if you don't care to have the value in a recognizable date format, you can just get your desired formatting like this (will give you a string that looks like this: YY/MM/DD/Time):

```
=MID(A1,3,2)&"/"&MID(A1,5,2)&"/"&MID(A1,7,2)&"/"&MID(A1,10,4)
```

Answer (score 1):

[ISO 8601 format would be `YYYY-MM-DD H24:MI:SS`.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-DATE-TABLE)

But you can set Postgres to accept various date styles by setting the [`datestyle`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-DATESTYLE) setting. You can do that [globally in `postgresql.conf`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/config-setting.html#CONFIG-SETTING-CONFIGURATION-FILE) or temporarily for your session.

```
SET datestyle = SQL, DMY
```

For more exotic formats, you can create a temporary staging table, `COPY` to it and `INSERT` into your target table from there. Among others, you can use [`to_timestamp()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-TABLE):

```
SELECT to_timestamp('13/10/14/17:33', 'YY/MM/DD/hh24:mi')
```

More info and example code in related answers like these:
[Replacing whitespace with sed in a CSV (to use w/ postgres copy command)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10158179/replacing-whitespace-with-sed-in-a-csv-to-use-w-postgres-copy-command/10190276#10190276)
[How to bulk insert only new rows in PostreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15834569/how-to-bulk-insert-only-new-rows-in-postresql/15834758#15834758)

Comment: =TEXT(A1,”yyyy-mm-ddThh:MM:ss”) is actual iso format (+/- fractional seconds and timezone). Apparently postgress couldn't be bothered with the T though so =TEXT(A1,”yyyy-mm-dd hh:MM:ss”)

Comment: @DirkBester: It's 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'. Case is not relevant for these parts. 'MM' would be month in Postgres. 'HH' would be 12-hour time in Postgres. And it is It is permitted in ISO 8601 to omit the 'T' character by mutual agreement.

Answer (score 0):

Your going to have to parse the date into four columns using fixed parsing.
Then reassemble the columns any way you want.
Just Google with excel parse columns fixed.