# Date/time formatting for table creation

Tags: postgresql, date, datetime, database-design, postgresql-copy

I am creating a table that will be populated with a `COPY`. Here's the format of that data:

```
6/30/2014  2:33:00 PM
MM-DD-YYYY HH:MM:SS ??
```

What would I use as the formatting for the `CREATE TABLE` statement?

```
CREATE TABLE practice (
Data_Time ????
)
```

One alternative might be to read as `varchar()` then format later. Seems convoluted tho.

Answer (score 2):

**Always** store timestamps as [`timestamp` (or `timestamptz`)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571392/ignoring-timezones-altogether-in-rails-and-postgresql/9576170#9576170).
Never use string types (`text`, `varchar`, ...) for that.

```
CREATE TABLE practice (
  practice_id serial PRIMARY KEY
, data_time timestamp NOT NULL
);
```

If your timestamp literals are clean and follow the standard `MDY` format, you can set the [**`DateStyle`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-DATESTYLE) temporarily for the transaction to read proper `timestamp` types directly:

```
BEGIN;
SET LOCAL datestyle = 'SQL, MDY';  -- works for your example
COPY practice (data_time) FROM '/path/to/file.csv';
COMMIT;
```

*Else*, your idea is not that bad: `COPY` to a temporary table with a `text` column, sanitize the data and `INSERT` timestamps from there possibly using [`to_timestamp()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-formatting.html). Example:

- [Formatting Date(YY:MM:DD:Time) in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19352020/formatting-dateyymmddtime-in-excel/19356008#19356008)

Answer (score -3):

You should pretty much never use vharchar() in postgres. Always use text. But it sounds to me like you want 2 columns

```
create table practice (date_time timestamp, format text)
```

Comment: There is no difference between text and varchar (without constraint!), so why bother?